# bcdebit not recognized

Tags: windows, windows-8.1

I need to write bcdebit /set IncreaseUserVA 2800 IN command prompt, but the answer is bcdebit not recognized .

Comment: Looks like a typo, [BCDEdit](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-US/us-en/library/cc709667(v=ws.10).aspx)

Answer (score 3):

#### I need to write bcdebit /set IncreaseUserVA 2800 in command prompt

The command should be `bcdedit` **not** `bcdebit`.

---

> The BCDEdit /set command sets a boot entry option value in the Windows
>   boot configuration data store (BCD) for Windows Vista, Windows 7,
>   Windows Server 2008, Windows 8, Windows 8.1, Windows Server 2012, and
>   Windows Server 2012 R2. Use the BCDEdit /set command to configure
>   specific boot entry elements, such as kernel debugger settings, memory
>   options, or options that enable test-signed kernel-mode code or load
>   alternate hardware abstraction layer (HAL) and kernel files. To remove
>   a boot entry option, use the BCDEdit /deletevalue command.

Source [BCDEdit /set](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff542202%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).